# Implementing multiple activities in one class

Tags: android, methods

I am creating an android app.  I need to implement two activities in one class, one which is a temperature sensor and the other is a google ad view.  In the same class I have two onResume methods, one for the sensor and one for the ad.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why do they need to be in one class ?

Comment: If you have specs like this, reconsider the value. But maybe you're just looking for [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) ...

Comment: What you need is two fragments within the same activity.